# Cordova ADAL Azure AD acquireTokenAsync fails with certificate error

Tags: android, ios, cordova, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm following [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) Microsoft Azure Cordova ADAL tutorial. I deployed the sample app to my android device using Visual Studio 2013 with all the latest updates.  When I type in the text box and press search, as expected, the app redirects me to the Microsoft provided login page where I should enter my business domain/tenant credentials to receive a token from Azure Active Directory.

The screen I'm redirected to is similar to the screen below. The only difference is where it says "Sign in", it lists my native client application name that I added to Azure AD in the Azure portal.
[image]

In, the app I enter my email address and move down to the password. Before I'm able to input the password, the page seems to POST and starts authenticating my inputted email address.  I think this is supposed to happen that way but that's not really my issue.

Shortly after it starts trying to authenticate my email address, I receive the following error:

```
Failed to authenticate: Code:-11 primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=fed.<mydomain>.com,OU=<private>,O=<private>,L=Boston,ST=Massachusetts,C=US;
Issued by: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US;
```

Generated from the `app.context.acquireTokenAsync` function below:

`// Attempt to authorize user silently
        app.context.acquireTokenSilentAsync("https://graph.windows.net", "myappclientid")
        .then(authCompletedCallback, function () {
            // We require user cridentials so triggers authentication dialog
            app.context.acquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", "myappclientid", "http://MyDirectorySearcherApp")
            .then(authCompletedCallback, function (err) {
                app.error("Failed to authenticate: " + err);
            });
        });`

**Can I please ask the Stack communities help in figuring out the cause/fix for this?  It's a roadblock to building our Cordova based Android/iOS app which requires Azure AD authentication.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have failed to deploy to your Android device the certificate(s) used by your local ADFS (or equivalent). ADAL will only allow connections that travel over valid SSLchannels, that is to say based on certificates whose CA chain is trusted and whose subject is a perfect match for the URL of the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, we found that deploying to iOS, the same exact app was able to authenticate with ADAL while on Android it was not able.

As it was explained to me by our networking team, they needed to switch from bridging to pass-through because the intermediate certificate was not reaching Android while iOS was able to go out and retrieve it on its own which explained why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is however on some phone models. To get over this go to Applications and disable or remove **Android WebView** app.

Comment: This isn't really a sustainable practice though.  Like I mentioned in my answer, it was due to an certificate issue rather than something that's installed on the device.